# Changing granularity of ticks in Seaborn lineplot on x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am pretty new to Seaborn so that may sounds like a stupid question but I want to change ticks in my X-axis (which is a date) on a `lineplot`.

I have created a graph as follows:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = sns.lineplot(data=to_plot.loc[ref_date:])
```

But I get this result:
[image: Seaborn lineplot with dates unreadable]

Obviously the dates cannot be read so I would like to have one tick for every 7 days.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually changed via Matplotlib, as Seaborn is a kind of wrapper around it.

Also, `sns.lineplot` return a `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` object.

This is what you can do

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker

loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=7.0) # To put a tick every seven days 
# plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))  # to change the size of the graph
# plt.title(f"Some super title")
# plt.ylabel("% active cases") # if you want to add a label in y-axis
axes = sns.lineplot(data=to_plot.loc[REF_DATE:])
axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
```

The result can look like this

[image: Improved ticks for x-axis]